# Database Design for Arbitrary User Submitted Database "Objects"

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I am working on a database software for a user with a need to store generic "objects" and associated information.  (With a web interface, to abstract the SQL)

First, what I mean by "object", in this situation, is an "thing" that can be defined by an arbitrary amount of input fields, for example:

A "Customer" object might be defined by

- Name
- Phone Number
- Email
- Company
- etc...

These objects are to be designed by the User.  Therefore, I need a way to define an arbitrary object in SQL.

The solution I have come up with so far is something along the lines of this:

```
    CREATE TABLE object_name
    (
        p_key SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        name varchar UNIQUE NOT NULL
    );

    CREATE TABLE field_type
    (
        p_key SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        type varchar UNIQUE NOT NULL
    );

    CREATE TABLE field_name
    (
        p_key SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        name varchar UNIQUE NOT NULL
    );

    CREATE TABLE object
    (
        object_name_id integer REFERENCES object_name (p_key),
        field_type_id integer REFERENCES field_type (p_key),
        field_name_id integer REFERENCES field_name (p_key),
        PRIMARY KEY (object_name_id, field_type_id, field_name_id)
    );
```

The basic idea is to use a junction table to define the amount/type of fields being used to define the object.  (This is just an extremely basic example)

I have a few problems that I am running into with this solution.

1. The user wants the field of an object to reference another object.  For example, in the "Customer" example I showed earlier, the "Company" field would likely be a selection from a list of "Company" objects.  This causes an issue, because a situation can be imagined where "Company" would also have a field referencing "Customer".  Meaning, there would be circular referencing... which object would be created first?
2. Is using SQL for defining the objects even a reasonable approach?  Or would defining an object be better suited to XML files?
3. Assuming the objects can be arbitrarily defined, what would be the best way of storing instances of the arbitrary objects?

Any breadcrumbs would be helpful.  Sidenote: I was thinking about using Django and postgresql as the framework.

Thank you.

Comment: How much complexity do you want? If you want to allow the "User" to create relational models of arbitrary complexity, then they should know how relational models work. Once they know that, they can write straight SQL DDL.

Comment: I am not entirely sure about the complexity yet, however my assumption is that the "User" defining the "Objects" will be somewhat familiar with relational ideas and not SQL.  The type of "User" who just creates instances of objects will be even more naive to the background process, so they both would need the web interface.

I will think more about the complexity though.

Comment: Sounds like you are really looking for a NoSQL

Comment: Thanks @John, I am looking into that now.